# Javascript Generate new Google Hangout and get URL

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-hangouts

I'm trying to build an app which allows me to spin up new hangouts. If I do something like this:

```
https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=[MY_API_ID]
```

I can generate a new hangout, but what I'm hoping to do is get the URL of the generated hangout so I can post it back in the app for users to join the session.

Comment: Have u able to get the Hangouturl? Please do tell me, I also want to generate a hagouturl and send it to the users for later use